# Download and unzip file in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been looking around for hours trying to find a solution to my problem.
My app uses roughly 25 html files to display content.
I would like the app to go online (when started), check if there is an update and download a zip file that includes the 25 html files and overwrite the old ones.
Been able to find bits and pieces, but nothing conclusive. Or i might just be slow.....
Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?
Thanks

Comment: I've used ZipArchive a fair amount (though only in restricted scenarios).  Encountered one bug, I think, but worked around it pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have used [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) in my couple of projects to unarchive the zip file and it is very fast and light weight. Here's a tutorial to learn: [how to unzip file using ZipArchive](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/08/13/unzipping-files-using-zip-archive/).

To download the file from the server, you can use the following way:

```
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://webspace.apiit.edu.my/intake-timetable/download_timetable/timetableXML.zip";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

There are lot of alternatives to download the files from the server, but this is the most common way to do it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i've managed to get the app to download the zip file, unzip the files, but i can't seem to see the new file!
NSLog shows all tasks completed, but when i old the web view the original file shows.
is there a refresh of sorts needed?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue, i didn't get.

Comment: when i press a button the app downloads the zip file and unzips the files in the documents directory.
but when i load my webview, the new html file is not loaded. instead its the old one, still.
is there a need for a web view "refresh" of sorts?
I do have overwrite:YES

Comment: Yes, you need to reload the html file in the webview.

Comment: if use this one download file then what's path use in apps....?

Answer (score 0):

If you have download the file to the documents directory then use `SSZipArchive` and call method `[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:@"PATH_TO_DOCUMENTS_FOLDER"]`

Downlaod [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)

Its pretty simple & you can choose to overwrite the existing files.